# What am I doing wrong in my russian doll caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, russian-doll-caching

This is my code:

```
<% cache(author_helper_method) do %>
  <div class="author">
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <% cache(author) do %>
        <h2>My name is <%= author.name %></h2>
        <% author.articles.each do |art| %>
          <p>I wrote: <span style="text-decoration: underline"><%= link_to art.name, articles_show_path(art) %> </span></p>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that my articles and article links aren't rendering except for the first one. Only the names are rendering. Here is what my page looks like:

> This is a terrible authors index page. One of the worst ever.
>
> Stats My name is Yasmeen Conn
>
> I wrote: some commenter
>
> My name is Kellen Marks
>
> My name is Dr. Hattie Durgan
>
> My name is Reta Glover Sr.
>
> My name is Keely Klocko
>
> My name is Michele Reinger
>
> My name is Josue Parisian

Only the names appear when I read from the russian doll cache and only the first article "some commenter" appears. Any idea why?

FYI, an author has many articles and an article belongs to an author.
Here is some other code if needed:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def author_helper_method
    count = Author.count
    max_updated_at = Author.maximum(:updated_at).try(:utc).try(:to_s, :number)
    "authors/all-#{count}-#{max_updated_at}"
  end
end
```

Comment: is it working in development?

Comment: this doenst look like a caching problem for me. if its not rendered, thern articles is [] .